# Can you save multiple separate lists to localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I'm working on a project that will take user input and store it into a list in localStorage. I want to be able to have three of these to do lists on the page.

I have put the code into three separate columns, however when I try to submit information in them, it seems to be adding the values in all of the columns to one list. I don't every use JS or Jquery, so I have been trying to learn as I go, and I'm stumped. This is the code that I am looking to run in three separate columns.

How do I make sure that the lists are stored in three separate places and also stored separately in localStorage?

```
       var list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todolist"));
// Checks for to dos in LS, if none starts with empty array
if (!Array.isArray(list)) {
  list = [];
}
function putOnPage() {
  $("#todo-list").empty(); // empties out the html
  var insideList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todolist"));
  if (!Array.isArray(insideList)) {
    insideList = [];
  }
  // todos to page
  for (var i = 0; i < insideList.length; i++) {
    var p = $("<p>").text(insideList[i]);
    var b = $("<button class='delete'>").text("x").attr("data-index", i);
    p.prepend(b);
    $("#todo-list").prepend(p);
  }
}
// rtodos on page load
putOnPage();
$(document).on("click", "button.delete", function() {
  var todolist = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todolist"));
  var currentIndex = $(this).attr("data-index");
  // deletes items
  todolist.splice(currentIndex, 1);
  list = todolist;
  localStorage.setItem("todolist", JSON.stringify(todolist));
  putOnPage();
});
$("input[type='submit']").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // changes input to variable and clears input field
  var val = $("input[type='text']").val();
  $("input[type='text']").val("");
  // adds to do to list and local storage
  list.push(val);
  localStorage.setItem("todolist", JSON.stringify(list));
  putOnPage();
});
```

Comment: Use different keys for localStorage; use different IDs for the elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably go with making the list an array with three object each one containing a separate column from the page, than update or set using something `list[0]` for list one, `list[1]` for list 2 and so on.

Or

You can approach it with using three stores in the localstorage one for each column.

JS Fiddle Example -> https://jsfiddle.net/jassMarok/3gcnyamp/18/

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")
var testObject = [{
    name: "todo-list1",
    items: ["Sell", "Buy", "Donate"]
  },
  {
    name: "todo-list2",
    items: ["Go", "Run", "Sleep"]
  },
  {
    name: "todo-list3",
    items: ["Work", "Program", "Code"]
  }
];
// Put the object into storage
localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function() {

  var lists = $('[id|="list"]');
  console.log(lists);
  var retrievedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('testObject'));
  console.log(retrievedObject)

  for (i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
    var $list = lists[i];
    var items = retrievedObject[i].items;
    for (j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
      console.log(items);
      $($list).append('<li><a href="#">' + items[j] + '</a></li>');
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button>Load Data</button>
  <hr/>
  <h3>
    List 1
  </h3>
  <ul id="list-1"></ul>
  <hr/>
  <h3>
    List 2
  </h3>
  <ul id="list-2"></ul>
  <hr/>
  <h3>
    List 3
  </h3>
  <ul id="list-3"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't link to code that answers the question. Post the code in the answer itself. Note that you can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to provide a runnable example much like jsFiddle here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @HereticMonkey stack snippets would not allow me to use localstorage API is there a way around that ?

Comment: Perhaps not (forgot about the sandbox attribute), nonetheless, you can still copy the code here in a normal code block.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Done, thanks for making me aware of the feature, gonna use it alot now :)